# TopAppBar is lagging when I use scrollBehavior

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I've been using scaffold instructure and topAppbar.And I'm using enterAlwaysScrollBehavior.But I have topAppbar lagging problem.I didn't understand why it's happening.And When I scroll the page enough , topAppBar would  be gone and lagging is removing. And code :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ScaffoldPageForFirm(
    onMenuIconClick: () -> Unit, pageSelection: @Composable (padding: PaddingValues) -> Unit
) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection), topBar = {
            TopAppBar(title = {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }, navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = onMenuIconClick) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.three_line_icon),
                        contentDescription = "navigationBar Icon",
                        modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                    )
                }
            }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                containerColor = GaziAcikMavi
            ),
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        }) { it ->
        pageSelection(it)
    }
}
```

Page selection is this :

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(paddingValues)) {
 LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) { .... }
}
```

I tried to put padding values in different states but didn't work.